# Black squares on checkbox fontawesome

Tags: html, checkbox, sass, font-awesome, laravel-blade

I'm getting this weird behaviour when using fontawesome:

[image]

Simply by adding `<input type="checkbox">` on my page, this 2 black squares shows up... I don't know if this helps, but the generated HTML is this one

```
<span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-square fa-base"></span><span class="second-icon fa fa-check-square fa-base"></span></span>
```

I searched a lot, but cannot found anyone with the same problem :(... Its worth to mention, that this is on a blade template file, I'm using fontawesome SCSS with Laravel mix.
Does anyone ever got something like this? I have no clue besides that this is fontawesome icons.

I appreciate any help.
Thank you very much!

EDIT: SOLVED...
For anyone that maybe struggle with this. I found that my problem was with one theme that I was using, called paper-dashboard, it was importing "bootstrap-checkbox-radio", and thats was causing the issue!

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue using paper dashboard. What did you actually mean by "importing"? cannot find such class from paper dashboard css

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what might be the problem but if you want to get rid of that you can used css to display none. you can refer those class like icons, first-icon using parent element so that other element using same class doesnot use the given css. And i will advice to create new project and add font-awesome in proper way. and it may be also the cause of javascript. There can be some javascript code in your project which is generating those icons.

Answer (score 0):

use css property to hide it.
display:none;
so it will not display

```
 #hide{
        display:none;    
      }
  <div id="hide"><span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fa fa-square 
  fa-base"></span>
 <span class="second-icon fa fa-check-square fa-base"></span></div>
```